# Как вызвать события при нажатия на кнопку enter?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть поле ввода имени и пароля, а также кнопка входа. После ввода правильного пароля и имени нужно, чтобы нажатие на кнопку enter вызывала функцию входа на сайт, а если введённый пароль или имя неправильные, то выводилось сообщение об ошибке ввода. Событие нажатие на enter должна срабатывать вне зависимости от того в каком поле находиться курсов и вне зависимости от того пользователь ввёл данные или нет. Реализовать надо с помощью чистого JS. Заранее спасибо.

```
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" id="Name">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="password" id="Pass">
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  function login () {
      console.log('Вы нажали ENTER')
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <input onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) login();" type="text" id="Name">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) login();" type="text" id="Pass">
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Русский народ - умный народ. Спасибо братан, я на stackoverflow.com с этими столько времени вожусь, а результата 0.